# How to have a common function in one component and use it in another component when a event emits?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some function in a component. 
Like `hello() { console.log('hello') }`.

And then I have  events which need to call the `hello` method in another component.

```html
<component1 eventName="eventName"> </component1>

<component2 eventName="eventName"> </component2>
```

In `component1.vue` and `component2.vue` there will be no code related to the `hello` method. But when the event is emitted, I need to have the below functionality when the event fires.

`component1.vue`:

`hello()` method executed.
`eventName()` method executed.

`component2.vue`:

`hello()` method executed.
`eventName()` method executed.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I am confused that if you have a common function why are you not using it in service ???

Comment: For common project-wide functions the best practice is to create them inside a single javascript _(or TypeScript depending on your taste)_ file, and then import the file in any component you want to use the functions. In addition, to the given file you could make exports like `export {function1, function2, ..., funcionX}` and then from inside your component you could do import like that `import {function2} from '../utils/my-common-functions.js'`.

Comment: This looks like a good use case for using mixins. Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options. You can read more here. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html